# AWS s3 "public access"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When going through my bucket Permissions --> Access Control --> Public access, I can tick the 'Everyone' option.

Does that mean that literally *everyone* will have access to this bucket files (given the url) ?

How can I give access to everyone connected through my user pool regardless of being the owner or not of a file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you give access control public then it should accessible by the entire world. What you can do is to set a bucket policy to restrict access to your bucket. In bucket policy, you can specify the users you want to connect. Please find a sample bucket policy below,

```js
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy12345",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt12345",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*", //* means public . Specify your users here
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
  }
 ]
}
```

In the 'Principal' section mention the users you want to connect (comma separated). Say for example if you have to ARNs to add in principal then,

```
 "Principal" :  {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root","arn:aws:iam::444455556666‌​:root"]}
```

and if there only one then,

```
"Principal" : {"AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"}
```

Please see more details about bucket policy [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

If you want object level permission instead of bucket level permission then go for access control list. Please find more details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)

Comment: Thanks !
If I want to restrict access to an user pool, I guess I need to use the 'Pool ARN' but what if I want to restrict it even more to a group of my user pool ? (they don't have any roles)

Comment: That group would have an ARN so you can specify group ARN there and it should work. An example group ARN would be like 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/Developers'

Comment: I have added roles ARN to my groups (List, read, write to s3). However, when I tried adding the code above and replacing '*' by the groupe role ARN and BUCKETNAME by the bucket name but got a "Invalid bucket policy Syntax" coming from the Principal...?

Comment: "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root","arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"]} can you try like this? here we have more than one ARN

Comment: My bad, I read more the documentation and found out I was missing '{ "AWS": "link_to_role_ARN"} (I was just putting the link_to_role_ARN)
Thanks again :)