# Having trouble granting public read permissions in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to understand the specific permissions I need to set on my Amazon S3 bucket. I've looked for this information already, but have only seen 1 or 2 examples of the new ACL/Policies that Amazon has implemented.

My use case: I'm using S3 to store images for my website (hosted elsewhere). I would like to upload images on S3 and be able to access them through their link on my own site.

I've used https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html to generate a GetObject policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

These are my current `Block public access` settings:

```
Block all public access: Off

Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs): On

Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs): On

Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies: Off


Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies: Off
```

In `Access Control List`, I have not added any permissions.

In `Bucket Policy`, I placed the policy I generated.

In `CORS configuration`, I specified localhost and my domain name as allowed origins and GET's as allowed methods.

Is this correct for my usage? It currently works, but I'm not 100% sure I've gotten the permissions right. All I need is public access to my photos (so my website can grab them) and to deny anything else (besides me logging in and uploading more photos).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934481/aws-s3-public-access but yes this is the correct way to do this. Feel free to post a comment if you run into problems down the line. The title is a little misleading since you are not having trouble making objects public.

Comment: @Simon I actually read that post as well, but it didn't do a good job of explaining if I got all of the access control settings right... Especially since that question is 2 years old.

Comment: In general, making objects public to the world is bad practice. If you're making it public to the world, you're essentially saying "Everyone has access, I just want the images to be visible." Ideally, if your website is running AWS, you can grant a role to the compute service that it's running on and update the Principal to only allow that component. Another thing to do is use CloudFront Origin Access Identity to only allow CloudFront to serve those images for your website.

Comment: If your website is not running on AWS, you can use federation via Cognito to grant the application permission to read from the bucket. The CORS configuration will not prevent users from accessing the object URI directly.

Comment: This support document is also much better at explaining, didn't realize that question was 2 year old, sorry. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: @Simon I'll take a look into the document you linked. I'm just wondering though, with my current configuration, are people able to POST/PUT/DEL or only able to GET? I'm just using the image URLs on a simple static website, and there's only 10 or so of them.

Comment: Because you've specified "s3:GetObject" only GET requests are allowed for the objects within the bucket.