# AWS S3 Access Denied Block public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Please help me from going insane here :)

I'm using AWS S3 and trying to give users access to some videos, I get access denied for all users for all objects when opening an object URL for public viewing, i.e. using a link of the format `https://<bucket name>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx.mp4.`

Thus, the solution provided for [AWS s3 "public access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934481/aws-s3-public-access) is not working for me, strangely enough.

I have set Block all public access to Off and created a bucket policy for the affected users, incl. root user, but nothing works.

[Here is the Block public access setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuOmk.png)

What does work, is when I set that all principals should have access, then "All principals have access.". So, it's all or nothing here.
For all other users nothing happens w.r.t. Public access. All users have browsing access and can open all files they have access to through the console.

So, the following "Bucket policy" is for all principals, incl. anonymous:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my bucket name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Here is the preview of external access result - All user access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yjrd.png)

and the following "Bucket policy" is not working for any principal, incl. root:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my account id>:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my bucket name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Here is the preview of external access result - No user access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvYUT.png)

I can have users login and use the Open file function, to view the movies. But as only Edge browser under certain conditions actually show the movie clips, I rather direct users to stream using VLC-player with static links of the format `https://<bucket name>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx.mp4.`

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you authenticate users when they use VLC? If anonymous access (Principal=*) works, this might be the missing part Have you had a look at presigned URLS? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You're of course right about the authentication using VLC. However, the problem is that 1. enabling public access for certain users is not working and 2. playin movies from S3 is very limited, i.e. not working in most browsers (the file is playing but no picture). I will check presigned URLs.

Comment: I've solved the playback (odd codec h.265-》h.264), but the limited public access problem still remain. The bucket policy should work?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Either access is public (i.e. everyone without credentials can get the file), or it's restricted and you need to provide credentials to get the file. How do you provide your credentials and how do you want to download the file?Maybe this is of help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html

Comment: I would like IAM users to be able to: 1. Sign in using IAM login, 2. Browse files in a bucket, 3. Open files using "Open" button and 4. Open files using "Copy URL" button + pasting link into browser. Currently, only 1, 2 and 3 are working fine. I'm trying bucket policies above to get 4. but I only get all or nothing.